# changing css style with javascript not working when full screen in Unity WebGL

Tags: javascript, html

I am showing/hiding div element with this code. It works fine, but once the app goes full screen, the div element stops updating. Ie it seems that when full screen, the changes in css are not working/updating anymore

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 122) {
        disableCartModal();
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 120) {
        enableCartModal();
    }
});

function disableCartModal() {
    document.getElementById("cart-modal").style.display = "none";
}

function enableCartModal() {
    document.getElementById("cart-modal").style.display = "block";
}
```

Fullscreen code

```
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler); document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler); document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler); document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler);
    
    function exitHandler() {
    
        var element = document.documentElement;
    
        if (element.requestFullScreen) {
           element.requestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
           element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        } 
}
```

Edit: I am running javascript from Unity WebGL

Comment: are you sure that the window you want actually has focus? (it doesn't make sense that a fullscreen window doesn't have focus, i know - but)  have you tried different browsers/OSes?

Comment: It could be that making the window bigger opens up a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), that overrides your changes to the display property of the cart modal. We don't see all your code, there's no [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so I cannot write this in an answer. You can find out whether this is the case by using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I am not sure how to check for the CSS media query, but it does update the css when checking in devtools. Ie the div css is changing display to "none" and to "block", but it's not doing anything in full screen. While not in full screen it actually shows an hides the div. It's as if somehow the css changes dont have effect on actual html when fullscreen. Not sure, but the css is still changing while in fullscreen, just does not do anything anymore..

Comment: I'm sure there's a perfectly reasonable explanation for this. The CSS media query was just the first thing that came to mind. You could try to build a minimal reproducible example, for instance by using a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/), or the "Code Block" button in the editor here. If you can show us what code can reproduce your problem, then we have a change to investigate why this happens. As the answer of JoSSte shows, we cannot reproduce it, and the most likely reason for this is that something is missing from the code in your question.

Comment: Mind you, by building a minimal reproducible example, you might find the cause of this problem yourself.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have added the fullscreen code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a Unity WebGL project, I was assuming that all the html/javascript code is a separate thing. But I was switching fullscreen with Unity Screen.fullscreen, which essentially completely blocked any updates to css.
So if by some chance anyone else comes to a situation, where they have Unity WebGL, that has to be full screen and they want to edit css through javascript called from Unity, make sure to trigger full screen from javascript itself, not from Unity.

Answer (score 2):

As `event.keyCode` is deprecated (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)) you could try to check for `event.key` (see values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values)).
Maybe your browser has dropped support or has the keys in question reserved for special actions.

Comment: Thanks, I might update to the keys, but I am getting the events fine. It all works fine, it just does not update css when full screen.

Comment: Edit: to clarify, it still updates css, but the css changes are not updating the html. ie in full screen the div does not get hidden/shown.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code and found it to work in both Firefox and Chrome... I added some debugging in the console to ensure things were firing as expected. I would suggest adding some debug statements to your code to make sure that you are hitting what you expect.

Also ensure that the part of the document you are testing has focus - testing, I found that if there are frames/ developer tools selected, the event would not be processed.

Also note, as [Bastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5457222/bastian-immanuel-andr%C3%A9) points out, this is NOT the recommended way to do keyboard events in modern browsers. Support may disappear.

Modern method:

```js
window.addEventListener(
    "keydown",
    (event) => {
        console.log("evt fired: " + event.key);
        if (event.key == "z") {//z
            console.log("z");
            disableCartModal();
        }

        if (event.key == "x") {//X
            console.log("x");
            enableCartModal();
        }
    },
    true
);
```

My experiment with your code (debug statements added):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>keytest</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div>Precart</div>
    <div id="cart-modal">Cart</div>
    <div>Postcart</div>
    <script>
        console.info("script commencing");
        document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
            console.log( "evt fired: "+ event.keyCode);
            if (event.keyCode == 122) {//Z
                console.log( "Z");
                disableCartModal();
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 120) {//X
                console.log( "X");
                enableCartModal();
            }
        });

        function disableCartModal() {
            document.getElementById("cart-modal").style.display = "none";
        }

        function enableCartModal() {
            document.getElementById("cart-modal").style.display = "block";
        }
        console.info("script done");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Did you test it in full screen? The code works fine as mentioned, ie its working as intended, but stops working when in full screen.

Comment: works in two browsers both versions... Firefox 111.0 and Chrome  111.0.5563.65

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you quite understand the meaning of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It doesn't help to just add a tiny bit of code to your question, you should try to create a complete example, and test it yourself, so we can work with it to try to reproduce your problem.

You can run my attempt below, even full screen, and you'll see it works just fine. At least, it does for me.

```js
function disableCartModal() {
    document.getElementById("cart-modal").style.display = "none";
}

function enableCartModal() {
    document.getElementById("cart-modal").style.display = "block";
}

window.addEventListener(
    "keydown",
    (event) => {
        console.log("evt fired: " + event.key);
        if (event.key == "z") { //z
            console.log("z");
            disableCartModal();
        }

        if (event.key == "x") { //X
            console.log("x");
            enableCartModal();
        }
    },
    true
); 

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler); document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler); document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler); document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler);
    
    function exitHandler() {
    
        var element = document.documentElement;
    
        if (element.requestFullScreen) {
           element.requestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
           element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        } 
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}
#cart-modal {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
    <div>Precart</div>
    <div id="cart-modal">Cart</div>
    <div>Postcart</div>
```

Comment: I am quite aware of what working example is.

Comment: @CosmicSeizure Prove it! No, just kidding. I understand you want to solve your problem with the minimum amount of effort.

Comment: I was about to make it today, it's reasonable thing to do, but you had to immediately school me on what is reproducible example. It is very typical here on stack overflow, it's a bit strange community. Still appreciate your time.

Comment: @CosmicSeizure I think my initial reaction was justified. In response to me asking for a MRE you added a few lines of code with the comment: _"I have added the fullscreen code."_, as if that should be enough. You didn't test it, nor can the code we got reproduce the problem. Yes, I got a bit frustrated and its good you got that. Normally I would stop there, but then you response with a snarky remark and so did I. So, here we are. I agree that this happens a lot on Stack Overflow. Me not understanding why you don't try to create a MRE and you irritated that we cannot help you without it.

Comment: Anyway, if you're were about to make it today, don't let me stop you. I'm almost certain if you do that you'll find the problem yourself.

Comment: I did, you were right. it was caused by switching to full screen in other way which was not native javascript.

Comment: @CosmicSeizure I'm happy to hear that you solved your problem. For your question to be useful to others, it could be helpful if you added an answer with the solution to your problem. You can even approve it as the correct answer. It would also satisfy my curiosity.